# How to add a check for VAT

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, vat, shipping-tax, tax-rule

Is it possible to add a check for shipping address on frontend?

I am not sure or know much about VAT and I am planning to put a check before customer purchase any goods from the website.

I have a website which is based in Europe and I can only ship the product to Australia and Italy and the website store which is Germany.

When a customer fill the details in the billing address automatically added into shipping address by default.

I want to allow users to ship the product to Australia and Italy and Germany only if they 
provide VAT for them country.

Basically VAT should match with the country.

Any help or advice I could take a look at